# Is this the best way to handle props that could be empty?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an scenario where I pass an array as a prop to a component. I then filter out the object I need based on an ID I passed as another prop. I do this with a computed property.

for example

```
people[
    {id: '1', name: 'Frank', age: '33'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Bethany', age: '22'},
    {id: '3', name: 'Roscoe', age: '44'},
  ]

<my-component :person-id="id" :peopleArray="people[]"></my-component>
```

I pre-fill the component data with empty strings in case the data I'm calling is empty

```
data: function(){
  personName: '',
  personAge: ''
},
```

and then use the computed property to to populate that data

```
computed: {
  getActivePersonById: function(){
    return this.people.find(x => x.id === '1')
  },
  getActivePersonName: function(){
    return this.personName = this.getActivePersonById.name
  },
  getActivePersonId: function(){
    return this.personName = this.getActivePersonById.age
  },
}
```

I then use the values in the HTML like so
(I'm resorting to :value because v-model was not updating from the computed property)

```
<label for="person_name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="person_name :value="personName">

<label for="person_age">Age</label>
<input type="text" name="person_age :value="personAge">
```

Finally I need to submit any updated data by the user, I can try grab the values from data or get the values with a js query. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this. I'd love to use the props data directly but I need to filter it by ID first.

Comment: An easier way is probably not to pass the entire `people` array into the prop, but simply pass the person whose ID matches the `id` parameter first. In other words, pre-filter the array before passing it into your component. In that way, you can also use `v-model` within the component itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties are by default getters  only i.e they just return a value. To use a computed property as a `v-model` you should make use of [computed setters.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

```
computed: {
    getActivePersonById: function(){
      return this.people.find(x => x.id === '1')
    },
    getActivePersonName: {
      get(){
        return this.getActivePersonById.name
      },
      set(newVal){
        this.personName = newVal
      }
    },
    getActivePersonAge: {
      get(){
        return this.getActivePersonById.age
      },
      set(newVal){
        this.personAge = newVal
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use these computed properties as `v-model` for your inputs

```
<label for="person_name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="person_name v-model="getActivePersonName">

<label for="person_age">Age</label>
<input type="text" name="person_age v-model="getActivePersonAge">
```

### or else

make use of the `created ()` lifecycle hook to initialize your data properties

```
created(){
  this.personName = this.getActivePersonName
  this.personAge = this.getActivePersonAge
}
```

**note:** in your computed properties just return values do not assign like you are doing

Comment: Thanks that looks like it'll solve my problem. I'll try it out in the morning :)

Comment: At the end you mention I should't use Computed Properties for assigning values. What should I be using in my scenario? Methods perhaps?

Comment: @ClintonGreen just return values in the computed properties and use those computed properties to assign other properties like in your case the computed propeerties are used to assign the values to data properties in created hook

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried this out and the Created() works like a charm but the get and set did not work. What does newVal refer to? is that what the get returns?

Comment: If you use computed setters, your computed key should no longer be a `function`, but an object with `get` and `set` keys, each being a `function`.

Comment: @ghybs thank you for correcting me....i just copied the code from the question and refactored it...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer. In my scenario both the computed setters and created solutions did not work.

However in a test with simpler data they did work. This was because I was initializing the component before the ID I was passing was available. I simply changed the component to only show when the ID was passed to it via v-if.

Now everything works fine. It was just a case of understanding how and when the component was initialized.

Comment: As ghybs mentioned out in the comment of my answer i had a mistake...edited the answer. Have a try